# What does "copy" do in a ffmpeg command line?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, libavcodec

I know that it copies something but other than that what does it do (to what extend it affects the output file)? Is it a switch or option? Why does it not have a hyphen before the word itself?

I see from other questions that it can [copy streams without transcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981707/ffmpeg-copy-streams-without-transcode) but what are other possibility that I can manipulate it?

I have done `ffmpeg --help` but I don't see any documentation about it. Is there a website I can read more about it?

Comment: I voted to close this question because, as the ffmpeg tag states: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on https://superuser.com/ or https://video.stackexchange.com/. Please delete this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`copy` is neither a switch nor an option. It's the value that can be set for the codec option, and means what it suggests i.e. copy the frames over instead of going through a decode->filter->encode process.

In the question you linked, the string is `-c copy`, which means set all codec operations to copy i.e. video, audio, subtitles, data and attachments, if any. `-c` is short for `-codec`.

If you set `-c:v copy`, it means to copy any video streams being processed. Same holds for `-c:a` or `-c:s` or `-c:d`. Of course, FFmpeg must support muxing the targeted stream into the output container. If it does not, the command will fail.

You cannot use audio/video/multimedia filters when asking to copy the stream over, since filters need to decode the audio/video frames and manipulate them. So their result needs to be re-encoded. You can, however, use bitstream filters with copy since those don't alter the main payload but only the associated metadata stored in the stream.

Comment: If you loose your audio streams despite using `copy`, try adding `-map 0:a -map 0:v`